# If $A∈M_{2×2}$ is a matrix that follows this condition $A^1+A^2=I_2$ show that A is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

If $A∈M_{2×2}(R)$ is a matrix that follows this condition $A^1+A^2=I_2$

show that, matrix A is **invertible**

Comment: Determinants are not additive.  But, Hint:  they are multiplicative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* $(A^{2019}+A^{2018})A=A^{2019}(A+I)=A^{2020}+A^{2019}=I$ gives inverses for $A$ and $A+I$.

Comment: @RGO, yes and yes: if $A$ has an inverse then it's invertible :-) If you need to use determinants, just use that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$.